# Catch value from within XML string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT [Details] FROM [History];
```

This is returning XML strings for `[Details]` like this:

```
<auditElement><field id="232131" type="4" name="Attachments" formatstring=""><oldValue>
<![CDATA[RB01B01_000001303; RB01B01_000001304]]></oldValue>
<newValue><![CDATA[ThisIsText]]></newValue></field></auditElement>

<auditElement><field id="232131" type="4" name="Attachments" formatstring=""><oldValue>
</oldValue>
<newValue><![CDATA[ThisIsText]]></newValue></field></auditElement>
```

So sometimes there is an `<oldValue>` and sometimes there isn't. Regardless, I want only return the `CDATA` within `<oldValue>` (or an empty row if there is no `<oldValue>`, so:

```
RB01B01_000001303; RB01B01_000001304
(NULL)
```

So I tried first

```
replace('<auditElement><field id="232131" type="4" name="Attachments" formatstring="">
<oldValue><![CDATA[', '', e.[Details]) as Details
```

but I get an error: `String or binary data would be truncated.`

How can I do this properly?

Comment: i think you can use `@xml.nodes` for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways, but try this query using the [value method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) of the xml type:

```
select x.value('(auditElement/*/oldValue)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as result 
from (select cast([Details] as xml) as x from [History]) a
```

I wasn't sure if your data already was typed as xml so I included a cast that might be unnecessary.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b76c7/1)